# xcode alert style, swift 3

Tags: swift, styles, alert, localnotification

so I have an app which fires a local notification after a certain amount of time. The only problem is that I require the alert style which pops up once the notification goes off to be an actual alert not a banner. From what I've researched I've found that you can request from the user, the ability to change the format of the notification (very much like requesting the use of notifications). I am however, unsure of how to implement this in code. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can achieve this? Any help on the topic is very much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need an alert for requesting authorization after the user changed their mind or first time when app is launched?

Comment: yes that's what I'm after but I am unsure of how to actually do that in code.

Comment: If the user changed their mind and stop using notifications for your app? You can get the authorization status by using getNotificationSettings method of UNUserNotificationCenter and that returns immediately. You'll get fast status results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification alerts, both local and remote, are handled by OS when the app is not in foreground and you have no control on them, on how appears. Only user can choose in Settings how they appears.
When the app is in foreground, instead, you can choose how to show them (or ignore at all, for example)

**EDIT**

After your comment, I suppose you want to know which notification alert style user chosen. In this case you should use:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(){ (settings) in

    switch settings.alertStyle{
        case .alert:                
            print("user prefers alert")                
        case .banner:                
            print("user prefers banner")                
        case .none:
            print("user disabled alerts")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but please see my comment added under the original question. This is what I'm after do you have any ideas regarding it?

Comment: @imjonu does my edit solve your question? do you need anything else?

Comment: No thats great! Thank you.